# Angular 4/5 route config broken

Tags: angular, routes

I have a root `AppModule` with the following routes (imported from an `AppRoutingModule`):

```
const routes:Routes = [
    {path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'home', loadChildren:'./home/home.module#HomeModule'},
 ];
```

The `AppComponent` has a `<router-outlet>`. The `HomeModule` has the following routes (imported from a `HomeRoutingModule`):

```
const routes:Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: HomeRootComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `HomeRootComponent` has a `<router-outlet>`.

When I navigate to the empty route, the router correctly redirects to the `/home` route and the `HomeModule` is instantiated (I log from the constructor). I expected the dashboard to be displayed within the `HomeRootComponent` outlet, itself within the `AppComponent` outlet.  However, neither the `HomeRootComponent`, nor the `DashboardComponent` gets instantiated. There is no error in the console.

Here is [a live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pfx-ng-zkcy7h?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

Comment: I could get it to work by importing the components directly in your `home-routing.module.ts` (https://stackblitz.com/edit/pfx-ng-zkcy7h-4q5vvf?file=app/home/home-routing.module.ts) For some reason, importing from the barrel results in the components being undefined. Maybe this has something to do with how stackblitz is bundling?

Comment: @LLai Thanks. I was trying to be clever with barrel use. I'll just change my imports and retest

Comment: @LLai you're right it works. Put that in an answer (or fix and un-delete your old answer) so I can give you credit!

Comment: When I created the repo on my machine, I got some warnings. The issue was circular dependencies (see answer for more info). So you could still use the barrel for your component definitions. Sorry, I accidentally overwrote my stackblitz from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by circular dependencies. When I recreated the repo on my machine, I got some warnings

```
src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts -> src/app/home/index.ts -> src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts
src/app/home/home.module.ts -> src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts -> src/app/home/index.ts -> src/app/home/home.module.ts
src/app/home/index.ts -> src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts -> src/app/home/index.ts
```

So basically, the routing module is importing the barrel which is importing the routing module.

If you want to still use a barrel for the components, I would remove the modules from the barrel and import the modules directly as needed.

```
// app/home/index.ts
export * from './home-root.component';
export * from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
```

Importing the home-routing module directly

```
// app/home/home.module.ts
import {HomeRoutingModule} from './home-routing.module';
import {DashboardComponent, HomeRootComponent} from './';
```

Here is the working stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/pfx-ng-zkcy7h-4q5vvf?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)